# É possível uma API Laravel consumir uma API Node e essa API Node chamar essa mesma API Laravel em uma request?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, node.js

Tenho um cliente (front-end) que consome um endpoint em uma API do Laravel, este endpoint se comunica com uma API em Node.js e essa API em Node.js chama métodos da API do Laravel (que chamou a API do Node), tudo isso acontecendo em uma única requisição e isso não está funcionando corretamente, a requisição entra em um "loop infinito" e demora muito para retornar alguma coisa, quando retorna dá um erro no Node:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo basicamente uma recursão infinita, sendo assim, se isso é realmente necessário, tente colocar um caso base para que em algum momento um não precise chamar o outro.

Comment: Verdade Luis, eu parei pra pensar e daria pra tirar essa requisição do Node que chama o Laravel, valeu pela dica!